# top value for element should be around -22px, but is somehow around -254px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So what I am doing simplified is adding 3 to the top value of `#searchInput`, which should be -22px before on scroll up.

But according to the console.log and the fact that I can't see the `#searchInput` on scroll up, the top value is around -254.

It is incremmenting up by 3 properly, but I don't know where that first number came from. It should be -22.

How can I fix it?

Here is the URL: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcdVZDcm1uVkJaUlE/KE_home.html

To replicate it:

1. Scroll down until the header is no longer in view
2. scroll up, but not enough so that the header is back in view

Here is my script:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log($('#searchInput').css('top'));
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st<=lastScrollTop){
    if(!isElementInViewport(document.getElementById('header'))){
        var pixelsScrollMoved = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('#searchInput').addClass('slideBack');
        while(parseFloat($('#searchInput').css('top'))<=32){
            var last_pixelsScrollMoved = pixelsScrollMoved;
        pixelsScrollMoved = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(last_pixelsScrollMoved = pixelsScrollMoved + 1){
            $('#searchInput').css('top', parseFloat($('#searchInput').css('top'))+3+'px');
            console.log('moved up one!');
        }
            break;
         }
         $('#headerTopBar').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0').fadeIn();
    }
    else{
        console.log('header in viewport');
    }
}
    lastScrollTop = st; 
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the `top` property of the element is set in pixels and not, e.g., the default `"auto"` or some other unit?

Comment: @StephenThomas Yes, line 247 of the view-source of the link: top:-22px;

Comment: not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but it seems position: fixed on .slideback is interfering with it

Comment: @LiviuA how so? I'm trying to have it fixed, but hidden off screen, then bring it on screen, sliding down, as the user scrolls up.

Comment: Did you mean to have `==` on the following line: `if(last_pixelsScrollMoved = pixelsScrollMoved + 1){`? And why do you have a `break` that always executes in the while loop? I don't get the logic of the while loop and the if-statement inside it.

Comment: @JohnS I did mean ===, but at second look, that line is redundant, so I removed it. Still have issue.